# Elasticsearch regexp with dynamic string contains special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a scenario to search results from elasticsearch using regexp and regexp expression is combine with dynamic string and expression. Sometime dynamic string also have special characters. Here is code snippet

```
filter: {
   bool: {
      must: [
        { term: { 'taxonomies.key' => path_key } },
        { regexp: { 'taxonomies.value' => "#{path_value}(\/.*)?" } }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have hierarchy structure content indexing similar like file system

```
Folder1  
  - Folder2
    - file 1
  - Folder2 test
    - file 2
  - folder 3 & 4
     - Training (Videos & Log-In Sheets)
```

Earlier code snippet was this -

```
filter: {
   bool: {
      must: [
        { term: { 'taxonomies.key' => path_key } },
        { prefix: { 'taxonomies.value' => path_value } }
      ]
   }
}
```

Initially I was using prefix matching which was working fine for me except when user were selecting "Folder2", it was returning file1 and file2 both which was wrong result then we change **regexp** and issue was solved. Now we are facing another issue if path value has special characters like () & etc. then we are not getting any result.

I have also tried to add escape special characters but couldn't get acceptable results.